# Set variable in static query

Tags: java, sql

I have a static query as `Select * from Emp where Empid in (?)` and I have that value of (?). I am not able to place that value. Please guide me. Let me know, I f anything else is required.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Hi Mureinik, there is nothing to share the code. i have fetch the data from DB as well as from JSP. and unable to set that value. please suggest me, how can I do that ? And, thanks for correcting the question.

Comment: is it because the method is static and the variable you want to set is not static, so in the method it is not available (due to static/non static fields? or are you trying to set it and at the DB level the variable is null?

Comment: Thanks  JB Nizet for the link. It really works....

Answer (score 1):

Try this java code:

```
public boolean yourMethod(String yuorValue) {
    String sql = "select * from user where fieldName = ?";
    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, yuorValue);//fieldvalue(1), Your passing value 
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    return rs.next(); 
 }
```